# beremote.exe high cpu utilization

Tags: windows-server-2008, backupexec, symantec

I have x64 windows 2008 R2 domain controller running on a VM with Symantec Backup Exec Remote Agent Utility installed.

Every night when backups run my nagios warns me that CPU utilization is 96% for about 3-4 hours while the backup is running. The offending process is of course beremote.exe. Symantec should only be backing up active directory and group policy from this server and I also have another domain controller with identical specs where beremote.exe does not kill the CPU in this manner.

Does anybody know of a hotfix for this particular issue? The only one I have found only applies to [server 2003](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;Q867667). I have also ensured that Backupexec is completely updated. Any ideas?

**Edit:**

Updating the Symantec Remote Client to the latest version did not fix this issue.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the client?

Comment: I have not. I will try that and see if it fixes the issue tonight.

Comment: How big is your AD DB? 3-4 hours to back up AD and GPOs seems like an abnormally long time.

Comment: What makes this server unique from the server with the same specs?  Do you have any other filter drivers to worry about (anti-virus, encryption)?  How's your VSS looking?  Do any system events correlate?  Additionally, although an API hook will greatly increase latency to the subsystem, may I suggest monitoring file system IO to see what file is "holding up" the backup process (I agree with Cheekaleak, so what's actually going on)?

Comment: The only thing that is unique is that this server has Group Policy and the other one does not.

Comment: And... answers my other questions?

Comment: We have been having power issues lately so I haven't had a chance to look at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was the server needed several critical Windows 2008 R2 patches. After applying these patches beremote.exe does not even exceed 50% of the CPU usage. Thanks for all the help and suggestions.